# Finding $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{x + \frac{1}{4x}}\; dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, arc-length

I am to determine the length of the curve given by polar equation $r = \sqrt{\theta}$ for $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. I know that this is the integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\theta + \frac{1}{4\theta}}\; d\theta.
$$
But I am not sure how to find this integral. I know that I should write
$$
\theta + \frac{1}{4\theta}
$$
as the square of something to do away with the radical.

Comment: Hmm... [seems difficult](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt(t+%2B+1%2F(4t))+from+0+to+2pi).

Comment: @user296602: That almost makes me feel better than I couldn't figure this out. If you write an answer detailing this I will accept.

Comment: Yet it looks so simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $\theta=u^2$ then $d\theta=2u\,du$ so we get:

$$\int \sqrt{\theta +\frac{1}{4\theta}}\,d\theta=\int \sqrt{u^2+\frac{1}{4u^2}}\cdot 2u\,du=\int\sqrt{4u^4+1}\,du$$

Wolfram Alpha gave a [monstrosity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt(x%5E4%2B1)) for this indefinite integral in terms of an elliptic integral.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we are considering the length of the graph of $\sqrt{\theta}$ over $[0,2\pi]$, this is the length of an arc of a parabola (the graph of $f(x)=x^2$ over $[0,\sqrt{2\pi}]$), which is also
$$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx =\left[\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1+4x^2}+\frac{1}{4}\text{arcsinh}(2x)\right]_{0}^{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}(8\pi +1)}+\frac{1}{4}\text{arcsinh}(2\sqrt{2\pi}).$$

If $r=\sqrt{\theta}$ means that we are considering the equation of a curve in polar coordinates, we cannot avoid elliptic integrals, as shown by Thomas Andrews.

Comment: I think it is $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{1+4x^4}\,dx.$

Comment: but $$\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4x}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4x^2+1}{x}}$$

Comment: i think your solution is wrong

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: the length of the graph of $f(x)=x^2$ over $[0,\sqrt{2\pi}]$ is $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: That is true if the points of the graph are $y=f(x)$, but this is a polar graph, $r=f(\theta).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: in such a case I misinterpreted the text, but the OP should have stated that the given equation is respect to polar coordinates.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think the statement of the problem in $r,\theta$ as opposed to $x,y$ makes that relatively clear.

Comment: Well, $r=\sqrt{\theta}$ might have been the first hint that it was polar coordinates. Then the tag "polar-coordinates" would confirm it. And the fact that the integral OP asked for was wrong for cartesian coordinates. But yes, the question could have been clearer.